# Топология маршрутизаторов

Tags: сеть

Например маршрутизаторы обмениваются топологией с другими маршрутизаторами. Можно ли сделать такую программу, которая будет отправлять такие данные:

Например до определенного адреса можно попасть через мой шлюз. Например что к сайту google можно попасть через мой маршрутизатор ( программу ), и получать пакеты запросов от других устройств. Я пока ещё мало прочитал про сети, и незнаю, обмениваются ли маршрутизаторы с нашими маршрутизаторами, которые дома установлены? Я прочитал что каждому маршрутизатору высылается полная топология. После этого для обнаружения кратчайшего пути ко всем остальным маршрутизаторам каждый маршрутизатор может использовать алгоритм дейкстры. И ещё. Когда маршрутизатор загружается, он отправляет специальный пакет HELLO, по всем линиям. Как мне узнать содержание этого пакета? В gns3 завиртуалить образы cisco и посмотреть сеть?

Comment: Предположу, что то, что вас интересует, называется BGP или EGP. Домашние роутеры ни в чём таком не участвуют, полная топология им неизвестна (провайдер выдаёт домашнему роутеру IP/подсеть/шлюз по DHCP — и хватит на этом)

Comment: А если отправить пакет HELO шлюзу, который выдал провайдер, он ответит своим именем?

Comment: Bgp,ospf,rip - на ваш выбор, протоколы маршрутизации.

Comment: нормальные провайдеры все эти пакеты порежут на коммутаторах еще на уровне доступа и вы никаких пакетов от их маршрутизаторов не увидите. Совершенно ни к чему гнать протоколы динамической маршрутизации туда, где их никто не поймет. А роутеры пользователей не понимают и не должны понимать

Comment: Даже в большой маршрутизируемой сети, при наличии внутри неё динамической маршрутизации, любой админ насмерть режет и вход, и выход пакетов протоколов динамической маршрутизации на границе с сетью, которая им не управляется (в т.ч. провайдерской).

Comment: Рекомендую почитать гл. 17 «Протоколы маршрутизации» Олиферов. (Олифер В.Г., Олифер Н.А. Компьютерные сети. Принципы, технологии, протоколы). Там всё описано в объёме, достаточном как минимум для устранения каши в формулировке вашего весьма объёмного вопроса.

Comment: Провайдеры, по просьбе клиентов и за доп плату :) отдают динамику по любому протоколу маршрутизации, это не сложно, редестрибутиться квагой например, бывшая зебра. Особенно если клиенты орендуют сети /24 у провайдера, то это обычно просто обязательно. Многие дешёвые маршрутизаторы из коробки поддерживают rip протокол. Чуть дороже как правило ещё умеют и ospf.